# Remove grey padding on top of android layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I added a NavigationView to my fragment and the drawer had an unnecessary grey top padding, I managed to remove this by adding `app:insetForeground="@null"` to it.

Now my layout is left with the top grey padding and I can't seem to remove it with the same method I used for the drawer.

[image: Text]

How can I remove this top grey part?

Comment: post your xml also

Comment: Seems it is because of your theme. Don't use themes with ActionBar. post your xml

Comment: Yeah i fixed it with .NoActionBar in themes, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `styles.xml` change from:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

PS: I saw your question at work but couldn't response earlier. That's why I write this answer, the specific could help others (with less coding experience) in the future. Cheers :)